# Use ImagesPipeline in nested items in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have empty arrays when I try to download images in scrapy and it seems a bit strange.
I followed the steps but it seems that the ImagePipeline doiesn't work with nested items. But it's important form me to conserve this articulation in my ouput Json file.

Here is my code:

```
    import json
import scrapy

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ccv_spiders.items import AuctionItem

class GlenMarchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'auctions_results'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with open('/home/bolgi/Workspace/Dev/python_workspace/ccv_spiders/ccv_spiders/json/input/db_urls_glenmarch_results_scrapy_reduced.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
            self.data = json.load(data_file)

    def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.data:
            request = scrapy.Request(item['gm_url'], callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['results'] = []

        for caritem in response.css("div.car-item-border"):
            data = AuctionItem()
            data["auction_house"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").get().split("-", 1)[0].strip()
            data["auction_country"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").get().rsplit(",", 1)[1].strip()
            data["auction_date"] = caritem.css("div.date::text").get().replace(",", "").strip()
            data["auction_url"] = caritem.css("div.view-auction a::attr(href)").get()
            data["img_urls"] = caritem.css("img.img-responsive::attr(src)").get()
            item['results'].append(data)

        yield item
```

The item file:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose

class AuctionItem(scrapy.Item):
    auction_house= scrapy.Field()
    auction_country= scrapy.Field()
    auction_date= scrapy.Field()
    auction_url= scrapy.Field()
    image_urls= scrapy.Field()

    pass
```

And the settings file:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,
}

IMAGES_STORE = 'images'

DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 1200
```

I don't understand how to download images in nested items with Scrapy...

Comment: Did you set `IMAGES_URLS_FIELD = "img_urls"`?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work. After that I change the item name for "image_urls" to respect the documentation. It doesn't work.

Comment: @QBolgi The `img_urls` field needs to be on the yielded item, because the pipeline processes only that. It does not process nested items inside the main item. So either put it in the `item` dict, or yield `data` instead.

Comment: Also, does your `img_urls` field contain anything? Or is that really what your question is about?

Comment: So it's going to be complicated because I have to use the url nested inculdied in the "results" item.

Comment: @QBolgi If you need your specific structure, then you can instead try a [custom images pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#custom-images-pipeline-example) where it looks for image URLs in the child items too.

Comment: Please, consider editing your question, including the title, to make it obvious that what you want it to use the ImagesPipeline with nested items. It’s an interesting question, you might want to open a feature request at https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues

Comment: I came here to say that I asked on GIthub and they say that Stackoverflow was better for this type of question haha